# How to forward messages from one outlook account to another and set conversation properties?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm currently working with 2 different e-mail accounts one of which is locked behind a citrix environment. For clarity I name the outlook account on citrix outlook A and the other one outlook B. In both instances Outlook 2013 is used.

I want to forward all messages from outlook A to outlook B to simplify things. I know how to do this using outlook rules.

Almost all of the e-mail I receive on outlook A are related to JIRA issues, which I want to be displayed as a conversation in outlook for all e-mails related to the same issue. Our Jira sends the e-mails with the same subject for all e-mails related to a single issue, however this is not enough for outlook to create a conversation out of it.

From [this post](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/9882301/is-possible-jira-email-as-outlook-conversation) it looks like adding "RE:" to the start of the e-mails will make outlook sort e-mails with the same subject into conversations, however this trick does not seem to work if you do it by forwarding an e-mail from outlook A to outlook B (and change FW to RE).

After some investigation it looks like this has to do with the properties of the e-mail objects in outlook. Specifically conversations in outlook seems to be controlled by the three properties [MailItem.ConversationTopic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869318.aspx), [MailItem.ConversationIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869408.aspx) and [MailItem.ConversationID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867895.aspx). My guess is that JIRA initially does not send e-mails with these properties, and that outlook sets them when receiving the e-mails and that if the subject contains "RE:" it sets them to be part of a conversation. However when forwarding e-mails from outlook A to outlook B these properties are sent with it so outlook will not look in the subject at all for determining if these e-mails should be part of a conversation.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836857/can-i-modify-conversation-id-in-outlook-by-vba-to-group-independent-emails) I tried creating a rule that would set the conversation properties on any jira-related e-mails that are received. However because the conversation properties are initially read-only this solution required the additioin of a [framework/library](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) which I cannot use in this instance because of company policies.

I'm hoping that maybe it's still possible to set the conversation properties when sending e-mails from outlook A to outlook B (so far I've only tried this for receiving e-mails in outlook A). However I have not found a way to do this. Is this possible without the use of an external framework/library?

Comment: Since based on what you're saying they're not REALLY a conversation, and it sounds like you just want to group them together.  Why not just make a "JIRA" folder and make a rule to move incoming Jira-related messages to it?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 JIRA tracks different issues, defects or work items. Whenever someone comments on or makes a change to an issue related to me I receive an e-mail about it. I want outlook to group together all e-mails related to the same issue, but not all e-mails from JIRA.

Comment: Ahh got ya... If they are being set by the first Exchange server/Outlook before being sent the second, you'll need to modify it BEFORE the 2nd Server receives it.  Which versions of Exchange are being used (for each Outlook account)?  What kind of permissions/access do you have to the Exchange servers these accounts are hosted on?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I only have access to my own e-mail, no further access to the exchange server.